# order of object creation, cpp

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

If I have an object `A` and I create 2 objects in one line like this:

```
A a1 = *(new A);
```

then the order of operations is this:

1. new object is constructed.
2. in order to create a1, it's CC is called with the newly created object

Now, what about having multiple "=" in one line?

```
A a2 = *(new A) = a1;
```

I compiled this code on ideone and got that only regular constructor was called here and = operator, but no CC, why is that?

I thought that what will happen will be:

1. new A will be created using CC on a1
2. a2 will be created using CC on *(new A)

Can you explain what I am missing?

Edit: I got it, Thanks !

Comment: Both examples leak memory like a sieve. No one would write such code in real world, such asking about is pretty useless IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mostly agree. but one might overload the global new operator (but if they do, this is still silly syntax to use)

Comment: Ok, it is a bad code, but still, I'm intersted in why = 
is called and not CC

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies operator = and CC are not necesserly the same function.

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies The second calls the assignment operator, because at that sequence point it's no longer part of the initialization.

Comment: @DavidHaim I know that. I guessed that in order to create the new A it will use CC and not =, and I cant figure out why it isn't going that way

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but why?? a1 is created first, is it not? and then the new A can use it as an argument

Comment: `A a2 = *(new A) = a1;` is equivilant to `A a2 = (*(new A) = a1);` the order of evaluation is from right to left

Comment: @DavidHaim and that helps how? the (new A) = a1 should be CC, in my understanding, and so is a2 = ...

Comment: @DavidHaim I'm not so sure if the order of evaluation is even specified for this case, or if it's implementation specific.

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies again, what if copy constructor and assignment operator do completly different things? how can you assume that?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ could be, but if not - how does the compiler interpret a=b=c?

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies post a ideone link with the complete code

Comment: @DavidHaim maybe I don't understand CC. I thought CC is called when we construct new object using another, and = is called only when we already have an object and just want to change it. Now, *(new A) = a1 seems to me like creating a new object, so CC should be called

Comment: @DavidHaim As `a=c;` and `b=c;`  in that or the reverse order.

Comment: @MarcoA. I already closed it. I'll try to rewrite it exactly the same

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies You're confusing `new` with initialization.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you explain? using new won't call CC ever?

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies Except for the explicit case `new A(A());` it won't, yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88916/discussion-between-cisforcoocckies-and--).

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies Nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When compiler meet this line of code `A a2 = *(new A) = a1;`  it does as fallowing:

1. Call default constructor of A for creating the object A (from the middle).
2. Call the operator= for copying a1 into new object created as step 1.
3. Call copy constructor for creating a2 using the result from step 2 .

However the compiler may or may not do some optimization on your code depending on the level of optimization from it's settings.

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies  that's rare.I tested just now the code and worked just as described.I used Visual Studio 2013.I got an operator = followed by a copy constructor

Comment: I can't find my earlier written code, so I will take your word for it :) thx

Answer (score 1):

Because *(new A) is already a constructed object, but copy constructor call happens to construct the left hand side object. In this case It is not required because the L.H.S object is fully constructed.